# I Eight Two Much

Tags: mathematics

If four 2s make eight, and three 2s also make eight, how many 2s do you need to make three eights, when you only have less than eight 2s?

Comment: Given the answer below, this isn't a logic puzzle.

Comment: Ah, okay! I didn't see the "brainteaser" label. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take three eights as twenty-four, and can do $(2+2)(2+2+2)$ to get there with five twos.  One or two of the plus signs can become multiplies.  There are other solutions, depending on what operations are allowed.  If we add division, we can multiply the above by $\frac 22$ and have solutions with seven twos.  If concatenation and factorials are allowed, there are $22+2$ with only three, and $(2+2)!$ with just two.

Comment: Oh wow, I mistyped. It's eight 2s, not eight 8s. Sorry!

Comment: If I take three eights as $24$, I can do $(2+2)\times (2+2+2)$ for five.

Comment: Correct! But there's another answer that also works. Can you guess what it is?

Comment: There are a number of others.  One or two of the plus signs can change to times (as long as they aren't both in the second group).  $(2+\frac 22)\times 2 \times 2 \times 2$ uses six, but still beats eight.  Taking off mine, you can do $(2+2)(2+2+2)\cdot \frac 22$ and still have only seven-I'm sure there are many more.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to add or multiply all of the 2s for the other answer.

Comment: You can also do $22+2$, or $(2+2+2)!$ for three.  It is not specified what are allowable operations.  The remarks about four and three imply that only addition and multiplication are allowed.

Comment: It is confusing, since now accepted answer does not correspond to the question...

Comment: @klm123:  the question has been edited.  I'll update the response.

Comment: (2+2)! is 24, not (2+2+2)!.

Answer (score 12):

Here's another way of producing three eights from five twos:

$$2 \times 2 \times {222} = 888$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the two initial examples given:

$$(2*2*2*2) + (2*2*2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way also assuming $3*8=24$ using $5*2$:

$$(2+2+2)*2*2$$

Answer (score 0):

Or, three eights is 8 × 8 × 8, which is 512.

8 × 8 × 8 = 2<sup>(2×2)</sup> × 2<sup>(2×2)</sup> × 2.

Comment: Or (using 5 `2`s like all the other answers): 2<sup>(2×2×2)</sup> × 2